# How to implement if..else.. condition in jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

IS it possible to impliment if...else.. statement in the  `data: {name: $('select#name').val(),area: $('select#area').val(),property: $('select#property').val(),bed: $('select#bed').val(),possessions: $('select#possession').val(),ptype: $('select#ptype').val()},` . For which i ll able to send single value each time to the next page .so plz help me how to add if else in jquery part below. here help will be appreciate Thank you in advance.

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.btnSearch').click(function(){
                makeAjaxRequest();
            });

            $('form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                makeAjaxRequest();
                return false;
            });

            function makeAjaxRequest() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'scr.php',
                    type: 'get',
                    data: {name: $('select#name').val(),area: $('select#area').val(),property: $('select#property').val(),bed: $('select#bed').val(),possessions: $('select#possession').val(),ptype: $('select#ptype').val()},
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

i ve tried this much some one help me why the if else condition is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.btnSearch').click(function(){
                makeAjaxRequest();
            });

            $('form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                makeAjaxRequest();
                return false;
            });

            function makeAjaxRequest() {
                var data;
                if ($('#name').val()!="") {
                    data = { name: $('select#name').val() };
                } else if ($('#area').val()!="") {
                    data = { area: $('select#area').val() };
                }
                else if($('#property').val()!="")
                {
                    data = {property: $('select#property').val()};
                }
                else if($('#bed').val()!="")
                {
                    data = {bed: $('select#bed').val()};
                }
                else if($('#possessions').val()!="")
                {
                    data = {possessions: $('select#possession').val()};
                }
                else if($('#ptype').val()!="")
                {
                    data = {ptype: $('select#ptype').val()};
                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'scr.php',
                    type: 'get',
                    data: data,
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? It's not clear what part of your code you want to modify.

Comment: @Seventoes i ve tried the above code

Comment: user can search from dynamic select box entry but the problem is i cant able to give if else condition to each select property.

Comment: Why are you showing us your PHP code? Is it relevant to the question, or just distracting to the people trying to answer it?

Comment: I'd like to order one SQL Injection in search.php, please.

Comment: @JLRishe for which no one ll be confuse where the data from the front page is going

Comment: data: {name: $('select#name').val(),area: $('select#area').val(),property: $('select#property').val(),bed: $('select#bed').val(),possessions: $('select#possession').val(),ptype: $('select#ptype').val()}, is it possible to add if else at this place?

Comment: @sameerkumar There is some sense in showing us the PHP for scr.php, but why show us the PHP for the front page? Can you show us the actual HTML as the browser perceives it? This question is about JavaScript, right?

Comment: @JLRishe yes i am sorry i am modifying now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do, but it sounds like you want to send data with only one property, based on some condition. You need to do so somewhere outside of the `$.ajax()` call; you can't use `if...else` inside an object literal:

```
function makeAjaxRequest() {
    var data;
    if (some condition) {
        data = { name: $('select#name').val() };
    } else if (some other condition) {
        data = { area: $('select#area').val() };
    }
    // etc....

    $.ajax({
        url: 'scr.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yes yes u r right @JLRishe but i dont know what condition to write in the if statement.

Comment: @sameerkumar Well, I certainly don't know what condition to use. It's your page. You're the only one who knows how it's supposed to work.

Comment: i am a new bie to jquery ajax so that is the problem am nt able to clarify much but i ve 5 select box user can select from those fields and search.@JLRishe

Comment: check i ve added the if else statement but it is not working ...@JLRishe

Answer (score 0):

If your only issue is sending a single value every time on selection of any of the dropdown, then this might help you... This solution will automatically create a property which can be sent to ajax without any if else clause or any condition

```
$("select").on("change", function (e) { // can specify the ids of the dropdown if you want some selected dropdowns to be in action
var currentSelection = $(this).val(); //Select value of the dropdown which is selected
currentId = $(this).attr("id");

//this will create your parameter dynamically.. it wont require and if else clause
var data = {};
data[currentId] = $(currentSelection).val();

//after ajax call clear the selection of all other dropdowns, so that every time only 1 dropdown is selected
$("select").not("#" + currentId + "").val(-1);
```

});

go through the link.. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/deep211087/d88ms2ku/)
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: (x > y) ? dataX : dataY,
success: success,
});
```